# Chrome always loading

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Chrome always loading when I run Xdebug in PhpStorm

PhpStorm config:

[image]

php.ini

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more details .. as I personally have no idea what you mean by "Chrome always loading"...

Comment: What @LazyOne says

Comment: You need to configure the [Xdebug remote log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544819-How-to-collect-remote-log-for-XDebug) properly, the path should be absolute and should lead to a file that exists and has all permissions.
In this log, you will be able to see what Xdebug is doing. I suspect that it's trying to connect to some host that can't be accessed or resolved (such as `www.test1.com`, for instance) and that's why it doesn't let Apache load the page.

Comment: idekey=PHPSTROM?  => PHPSTORM. The `remote_handler` default **IS** dbgp, so that setting can be eliminated. (I don't use it) Also, the `remote_connect_back` setting ignores the `remote_host` setting, so you might remove the `remote_connect_back` too. (see the [Xdebug docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) for the various settings details)

Comment: What details do you need?I think the picture is very detailed.I need help.When I click on the break point, it won't work.Can I email you? can you tell me your email address?